# Kafka streams throwing InvalidProducerException frequently

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have a kafka streams application with 4 instances, each runing on a separate ec2 instance with 16 threads. Total threads = 16 * 4. The input topic has only 32 partitions. I understand that some of the threads will remain idle.

I am continously seeing this exception

```
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.InvalidProducerEpochException: Producer attempted to produce with an old epoch.
01:57:23.971 [kafka-producer-network-thread | bids_kafka_streams_beta_007-fd78c6fa-62bc-437d-add0-c31f5b7c1901-StreamThread-12-1_6-producer] ERROR org.apach
e.kafka.streams.processor.internals.RecordCollectorImpl - stream-thread [bids_kafka_streams_beta_007-fd78c6fa-62bc-437d-add0-c31f5b7c1901-StreamThread-12] t
ask [1_6] Error encountered sending record to topic kafka_streams_bids_output for task 1_6 due to:
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.InvalidProducerEpochException: Producer attempted to produce with an old epoch.
Written offsets would not be recorded and no more records would be sent since the producer is fenced, indicating the task may be migrated out
```

The only settings I have change in the streams config are the producer configs to reduce CPU usage on brokers

```
linger.ms=10000
commit.interval.ms=10000
```

Records are windowed by 2 mins

Is it due to rebalancing? Why so frequent?

Comment: @Matthias J. Sax Can you please help on this?