# InvalidProducerEpochException loop on kafka stream app

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have multiple ktable-ktable join kafka stream application which is running on kubernetes.

At some point, I see a graph like below on the disk usage.

[image: disk loop]

After the investigation, I see that there is an exception called InvalidProducerEpochException. It is change application state as follow

- RUNNING to PARTITIONS_REVOKED
- RUNNING to REBALANCING
- Then tried to restore changelog state store (approximately 30 min. to finish)

To get more clear log, I change log level to TRACE. The exception trace I get when the problem occurs.

```
[2021-06-03 05:40:23,430] TRACE Failed to produce messages to x-changelog-0 with base offset -1. (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.ProducerBatch)
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.InvalidProducerEpochException: Producer attempted to produce with an old epoch.
[2021-06-03 05:40:23,430] TRACE Failed to produce messages to x-changelog-0 with base offset -1. (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.ProducerBatch)
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.InvalidProducerEpochException: Producer attempted to produce with an old epoch.
[2021-06-03 05:40:23,430] ERROR stream-thread [test1-88266093-e40c-4612-bff5-caafa3e21b4a-StreamThread-1] task [1_0] Error encountered sending record to topic x-changelog for task 1_0 due to:
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.InvalidProducerEpochException: Producer attempted to produce with an old epoch.
Written offsets would not be recorded and no more records would be sent since the producer is fenced, indicating the task may be migrated out (org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.RecordCollectorImpl)
[2021-06-03 05:40:23,430] ERROR stream-thread [test1-88266093-e40c-4612-bff5-caafa3e21b4a-StreamThread-1] task [1_0] Error encountered sending record to topic x-changelog for task 1_0 due to:
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.InvalidProducerEpochException: Producer attempted to produce with an old epoch.
Written offsets would not be recorded and no more records would be sent since the producer is fenced, indicating the task may be migrated out (org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.RecordCollectorImpl)
[2021-06-03 05:40:23,431] TRACE stream-thread [test1-88266093-e40c-4612-bff5-caafa3e21b4a-StreamThread-1] task [1_0] Failed record: (key \x00\x00\x00\x00\x00w\xFA\xC1 value [0, 0, 0, 0, 39, 76, 18, 50, 49, 51, 53, 49, 48, 49, 55, 52, 4, 72, 82, 18, 50, 49, 51, 53, 49, 55, 51, 50, 56, 4, 83, 73, 18, 50, 49, 51, 53, 48, 56, 49, 51, 48, 4, 76, 85, 18, 50, 49, 51, 53, 48, 51, 48, 50, 48, 4, 68, 75, 18, 50, 49, 51, 53, 49, 54, 56, 49, 55, 4, 83, 75, 18, 50, 49, 51, 53, 48, 53, 48, 54, 52, 4, 73, 69, 18, 50, 49, 51, 53, 48, 52, 53, 53, 51, 4, 71, 66, 18, 50, 49, 51, 53, 48, 57, 54, 54, 51, 4, 66, 65, 18, 50, 49, 51, 53, 48, 54, 53, 57, 55, 4, 73, 84, 18, 50, 49, 51, 53, 48, 49, 52, 56, 55, 4, 65, 84, 18, 50, 49, 51, 53, 49, 49, 55, 48, 55, 4, 78, 79, 18, 50, 49, 51, 53, 49, 56, 51, 53, 48, 4, 83, 70, 18, 50, 49, 51, 53, 48, 55, 49, 48, 56, 6, 71, 66, 75, 18, 50, 49, 51, 53, 48, 48, 57, 55, 54, 4, 68, 69, 18, 50, 49, 51, 53, 49, 50, 50, 49, 56, 4, 82, 79, 18, 50, 49, 51, 53, 49, 53, 50, 56, 52, 4, 81, 90, 18, 50, 49, 51, 53, 49, 57, 56, 56, 51, 4, 67, 90, 18, 50, 49, 51, 53, 49, 51, 50, 52, 48, 4, 80, 76, 18, 50, 49, 51, 53, 49, 52, 55, 55, 51, 4, 73, 83, 18, 50, 49, 51, 53, 48, 57, 49, 53, 50, 4, 71, 82, 18, 50, 49, 51, 53, 49, 51, 55, 53, 49, 4, 70, 73, 18, 50, 49, 51, 53, 49, 49, 49, 57, 54, 4, 65, 76, 18, 50, 49, 51, 53, 49, 54, 51, 48, 54, 4, 82, 83, 18, 50, 49, 51, 53, 48, 54, 48, 56, 54, 4, 67, 72, 18, 50, 49, 51, 53, 49, 55, 56, 51, 57, 4, 77, 84, 18, 50, 49, 51, 53, 48, 52, 48, 52, 50, 4, 78, 76, 18, 50, 49, 51, 53, 48, 51, 53, 51, 49, 4, 70, 82, 18, 50, 49, 51, 53, 48, 53, 53, 55, 53, 4, 69, 83, 18, 50, 49, 51, 53, 48, 56, 54, 52, 49, 4, 77, 67, 18, 50, 49, 51, 53, 48, 55, 54, 49, 57, 4, 76, 73, 18, 50, 49, 51, 53, 49, 50, 55, 50, 57, 4, 72, 85, 18, 50, 49, 51, 53, 49, 57, 51, 55, 50, 4, 77, 68, 18, 50, 49, 51, 53, 48, 49, 57, 57, 56, 4, 66, 69, 18, 50, 49, 51, 53, 49, 56, 56, 54, 49, 4, 77, 69, 18, 50, 49, 51, 53, 48, 50, 53, 48, 57, 4, 66, 71, 18, 50, 49, 51, 53, 49, 52, 50, 54, 50, 4, 80, 84, 18, 50, 49, 51, 53, 49, 48, 54, 56, 53, 4, 83, 69, 18, 50, 49, 51, 53, 49, 53, 55, 57, 53, 4, 77, 75, 0] timestamp 1622642592862) topic=[x-changelog] partition=[0] (org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.RecordCollectorImpl)
[2021-06-03 05:40:23,431] TRACE stream-thread [test1-88266093-e40c-4612-bff5-caafa3e21b4a-StreamThread-1] task [1_0] Failed record: (key \x00\x00\x00\x00\x00w\xFA\xC1 value [0, 0, 0, 0, 39, 76, 18, 50, 49, 51, 53, 49, 48, 49, 55, 52, 4, 72, 82, 18, 50, 49, 51, 53, 49, 55, 51, 50, 56, 4, 83, 73, 18, 50, 49, 51, 53, 48, 56, 49, 51, 48, 4, 76, 85, 18, 50, 49, 51, 53, 48, 51, 48, 50, 48, 4, 68, 75, 18, 50, 49, 51, 53, 49, 54, 56, 49, 55, 4, 83, 75, 18, 50, 49, 51, 53, 48, 53, 48, 54, 52, 4, 73, 69, 18, 50, 49, 51, 53, 48, 52, 53, 53, 51, 4, 71, 66, 18, 50, 49, 51, 53, 48, 57, 54, 54, 51, 4, 66, 65, 18, 50, 49, 51, 53, 48, 54, 53, 57, 55, 4, 73, 84, 18, 50, 49, 51, 53, 48, 49, 52, 56, 55, 4, 65, 84, 18, 50, 49, 51, 53, 49, 49, 55, 48, 55, 4, 78, 79, 18, 50, 49, 51, 53, 49, 56, 51, 53, 48, 4, 83, 70, 18, 50, 49, 51, 53, 48, 55, 49, 48, 56, 6, 71, 66, 75, 18, 50, 49, 51, 53, 48, 48, 57, 55, 54, 4, 68, 69, 18, 50, 49, 51, 53, 49, 50, 50, 49, 56, 4, 82, 79, 18, 50, 49, 51, 53, 49, 53, 50, 56, 52, 4, 81, 90, 18, 50, 49, 51, 53, 49, 57, 56, 56, 51, 4, 67, 90, 18, 50, 49, 51, 53, 49, 51, 50, 52, 48, 4, 80, 76, 18, 50, 49, 51, 53, 49, 52, 55, 55, 51, 4, 73, 83, 18, 50, 49, 51, 53, 48, 57, 49, 53, 50, 4, 71, 82, 18, 50, 49, 51, 53, 49, 51, 55, 53, 49, 4, 70, 73, 18, 50, 49, 51, 53, 49, 49, 49, 57, 54, 4, 65, 76, 18, 50, 49, 51, 53, 49, 54, 51, 48, 54, 4, 82, 83, 18, 50, 49, 51, 53, 48, 54, 48, 56, 54, 4, 67, 72, 18, 50, 49, 51, 53, 49, 55, 56, 51, 57, 4, 77, 84, 18, 50, 49, 51, 53, 48, 52, 48, 52, 50, 4, 78, 76, 18, 50, 49, 51, 53, 48, 51, 53, 51, 49, 4, 70, 82, 18, 50, 49, 51, 53, 48, 53, 53, 55, 53, 4, 69, 83, 18, 50, 49, 51, 53, 48, 56, 54, 52, 49, 4, 77, 67, 18, 50, 49, 51, 53, 48, 55, 54, 49, 57, 4, 76, 73, 18, 50, 49, 51, 53, 49, 50, 55, 50, 57, 4, 72, 85, 18, 50, 49, 51, 53, 49, 57, 51, 55, 50, 4, 77, 68, 18, 50, 49, 51, 53, 48, 49, 57, 57, 56, 4, 66, 69, 18, 50, 49, 51, 53, 49, 56, 56, 54, 49, 4, 77, 69, 18, 50, 49, 51, 53, 48, 50, 53, 48, 57, 4, 66, 71, 18, 50, 49, 51, 53, 49, 52, 50, 54, 50, 4, 80, 84, 18, 50, 49, 51, 53, 49, 48, 54, 56, 53, 4, 83, 69, 18, 50, 49, 51, 53, 49, 53, 55, 57, 53, 4, 77, 75, 0] timestamp 1622642592862) topic=[x-changelog] partition=[0] (org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.RecordCollectorImpl)
[2021-06-03 05:40:23,431] TRACE [Producer clientId=test1-88266093-e40c-4612-bff5-caafa3e21b4a-StreamThread-1-1_0-producer, transactionalId=test1-1_0] Received produce response from node 0 with correlation id 829 (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender)
[2021-06-03 05:40:23,431] TRACE [Producer clientId=test1-88266093-e40c-4612-bff5-caafa3e21b4a-StreamThread-1-1_0-producer, transactionalId=test1-1_0] Received produce response from node 0 with correlation id 829 (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender)
[2021-06-03 05:40:23,431] INFO [Producer clientId=test1-88266093-e40c-4612-bff5-caafa3e21b4a-StreamThread-1-1_0-producer, transactionalId=test1-1_0] Transiting to abortable error state due to org.apache.kafka.common.errors.InvalidProducerEpochException: Producer attempted to produce with an old epoch. (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.TransactionManager)
[2021-06-03 05:40:23,431] INFO [Producer clientId=test1-88266093-e40c-4612-bff5-caafa3e21b4a-StreamThread-1-1_0-producer, transactionalId=test1-1_0] Resetting sequence number of batch with current sequence 273 for partition test-0 to 272 (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.TransactionManager)
[2021-06-03 05:40:23,431] INFO Resetting sequence number of batch with current sequence 273 for partition test-0 to 272 (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.ProducerBatch)
[2021-06-03 05:40:23,431] INFO Resetting sequence number of batch with current sequence 273 for partition test-0 to 272 (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.ProducerBatch)
[2021-06-03 05:40:23,431] TRACE Failed to produce messages to test-0 with base offset -1. (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.ProducerBatch)
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.InvalidProducerEpochException: Producer attempted to produce with an old epoch.
[2021-06-03 05:40:23,431] TRACE Failed to produce messages to test-0 with base offset -1. (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.ProducerBatch)
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.InvalidProducerEpochException: Producer attempted to produce with an old epoch.
[2021-06-03 05:40:23,431] TRACE [Producer clientId=test1-88266093-e40c-4612-bff5-caafa3e21b4a-StreamThread-1-1_0-producer, transactionalId=test1-1_0] Received produce response from node 1 with correlation id 832 (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender)
[2021-06-03 05:40:23,431] TRACE [Producer clientId=test1-88266093-e40c-4612-bff5-caafa3e21b4a-StreamThread-1-1_0-producer, transactionalId=test1-1_0] Received produce response from node 1 with correlation id 832 (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender)
[2021-06-03 05:40:23,431] INFO [Producer clientId=test1-88266093-e40c-4612-bff5-caafa3e21b4a-StreamThread-1-1_0-producer, transactionalId=test1-1_0] Transiting to abortable error state due to org.apache.kafka.common.errors.InvalidProducerEpochException: Producer attempted to produce with an old epoch. (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.TransactionManager)
[2021-06-03 05:40:23,431] TRACE Failed to produce messages to x-changelog-0 with base offset -1. (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.ProducerBatch)
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.InvalidProducerEpochException: Producer attempted to produce with an old epoch.
[2021-06-03 05:40:23,431] TRACE Failed to produce messages to x-changelog-0 with base offset -1. (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.ProducerBatch)
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.InvalidProducerEpochException: Producer attempted to produce with an old epoch.
[2021-06-03 05:40:23,431] TRACE [Producer clientId=test1-88266093-e40c-4612-bff5-caafa3e21b4a-StreamThread-1-1_0-producer, transactionalId=test1-1_0] Received produce response from node 0 with correlation id 831 (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender)
[2021-06-03 05:40:23,431] TRACE [Producer clientId=test1-88266093-e40c-4612-bff5-caafa3e21b4a-StreamThread-1-1_0-producer, transactionalId=test1-1_0] Received produce response from node 0 with correlation id 831 (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender)
[2021-06-03 05:40:23,431] INFO [Producer clientId=test1-88266093-e40c-4612-bff5-caafa3e21b4a-StreamThread-1-1_0-producer, transactionalId=test1-1_0] Transiting to abortable error state due to org.apache.kafka.common.errors.InvalidProducerEpochException: Producer attempted to produce with an old epoch. (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.TransactionManager)
[2021-06-03 05:40:23,431] TRACE Failed to produce messages to test-0 with base offset -1. (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.ProducerBatch)
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.InvalidProducerEpochException: Producer attempted to produce with an old epoch.
[2021-06-03 05:40:23,431] TRACE Failed to produce messages to test-0 with base offset -1. (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.ProducerBatch)
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.InvalidProducerEpochException: Producer attempted to produce with an old epoch.
[2021-06-03 05:40:23,462] ERROR stream-thread [test1-88266093-e40c-4612-bff5-caafa3e21b4a-StreamThread-1] task [1_0] Failed to flush cache of store closed-country-product-join-country-list-aggregate:  (org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorStateManager)
org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.TaskMigratedException: Error encountered sending record to topic x-changelog for task 1_0 due to:
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.InvalidProducerEpochException: Producer attempted to produce with an old epoch.
Written offsets would not be recorded and no more records would be sent since the producer is fenced, indicating the task may be migrated out; it means all tasks belonging to this thread should be migrated.
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.RecordCollectorImpl.recordSendError(RecordCollectorImpl.java:206)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.RecordCollectorImpl.lambda$send$0(RecordCollectorImpl.java:187)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer$InterceptorCallback.onCompletion(KafkaProducer.java:1366)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.ProducerBatch.completeFutureAndFireCallbacks(ProducerBatch.java:231)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.ProducerBatch.done(ProducerBatch.java:197)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.failBatch(Sender.java:690)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.failBatch(Sender.java:676)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.completeBatch(Sender.java:634)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.handleProduceResponse(Sender.java:568)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.lambda$sendProduceRequest$0(Sender.java:757)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.ClientResponse.onComplete(ClientResponse.java:109)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.completeResponses(NetworkClient.java:586)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.poll(NetworkClient.java:578)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.runOnce(Sender.java:325)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.run(Sender.java:240)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.InvalidProducerEpochException: Producer attempted to produce with an old epoch.
[2021-06-03 05:40:23,463] WARN stream-thread [test1-88266093-e40c-4612-bff5-caafa3e21b4a-StreamThread-1] Detected that the thread is being fenced. This implies that this thread missed a rebalance and dropped out of the consumer group. Will close out all assigned tasks and rejoin the consumer group. (org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread)
org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.TaskMigratedException: Error encountered sending record to topic x-changelog for task 1_0 due to:
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.InvalidProducerEpochException: Producer attempted to produce with an old epoch.
Written offsets would not be recorded and no more records would be sent since the producer is fenced, indicating the task may be migrated out; it means all tasks belonging to this thread should be migrated.
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.RecordCollectorImpl.recordSendError(RecordCollectorImpl.java:206)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.RecordCollectorImpl.lambda$send$0(RecordCollectorImpl.java:187)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer$InterceptorCallback.onCompletion(KafkaProducer.java:1366)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.ProducerBatch.completeFutureAndFireCallbacks(ProducerBatch.java:231)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.ProducerBatch.done(ProducerBatch.java:197)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.failBatch(Sender.java:690)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.failBatch(Sender.java:676)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.completeBatch(Sender.java:634)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.handleProduceResponse(Sender.java:568)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.lambda$sendProduceRequest$0(Sender.java:757)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.ClientResponse.onComplete(ClientResponse.java:109)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.completeResponses(NetworkClient.java:586)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.poll(NetworkClient.java:578)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.runOnce(Sender.java:325)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.run(Sender.java:240)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.InvalidProducerEpochException: Producer attempted to produce with an old epoch.
```

NOTE: If I delete the deployment and start it again. It is working normally until some point, then the exception occurs again and again.

[Kafka streams throwing InvalidProducerException frequently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67259990/kafka-streams-throwing-invalidproducerexception-frequently) (This could be same problem with me.)

- What is the main cause of the InvalidProducerEpochException ?
- Why it is so frequent ?
- How could I reduce state restoration time ? (up to 5 minutes ok)

Thanks

Comment: What version of the Kafka Streams client library are you using?

Comment: `kafka-streams 6.1.1-ccs`